# using strict is making jshint unusable

Tags: javascript, jshint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jslint requires “using strict” - what does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107000/jslint-requires-using-strict-what-does-this-mean)

I keep getting errors about

```
Line 38: return (document.getElementById(a).innerHTML=b);
Missing "use strict" statement.
```

here

http://www.jshint.com/

I don't know to get rid of them or what they mean.

A prevous post suggest I user

```
"use strict";
```

and wrap all my code in a self-executing anonymous method..but this seemed a bit extrme...or maybe I just don't undersand javascript..is this what I should indeed do?

Comment: It is best to edit and improve your original question instead of asking similar ones in quick sucession.

Comment: So, even if it is legal, why do you insist on an assignment in a return statement? It doesn't make your code better, just harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all about strict mode at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode)

**Example**:

```
function sum(a, a, c) // !!! syntax error
{
  "use strict";
  return a + b + c; // wrong if this code ran
}
```

Basically strict mode enables modern browsers to run additional checks on your code.

Comment: This is a bug..that I can not define it globally.  I'm not going to put it in each function...if jshint checks against strict...why does it even care if I set "use strict"

Comment: If you are annoyed by this warnings you can simply uncheck ' When code is not in strict mode' on the jsHint site.

Comment: You can invoke strict mode on a entire script, see first section of the MDN docs