# How do I pass global config to jshint?

Tags: javascript, jshint

How do I pass global config to jshint? I didn't find the answer in the documentation.

My config file:

```
>type tests\jshint_options.js
/*jshint globalstrict:true */
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
>jshint myfile.js --config=tests\jshint_options.js
myfile.js: line 1, col 1, Use the function form of "use strict".
myfile.js: line 4, col 24, Unescaped '['.
myfile.js: line 4, col 49, Unescaped '['.

3 errors

>jshint myfile.js --config tests\jshint_options.js

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at _loadAndParseConfig (C:\Users\RONG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jshint\lib\cli.js:28:18)
    at Object.interpret (C:\Users\RONG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jshint\lib\cli.js:114:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RONG\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jshint\bin\hint:2:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)

>
```

Comment: FYI, opened an issue to document this: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/483

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After much digging, I found this [helpful blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2011/09/jshint.html) that reveled ...

that the config file is in JSON format, not javascript comments!

```
{
    "supernew": true
}
```

P.S.

This is actually documented in [nodejs-jshint documentations](https://github.com/jshint/node-jshint)! Not sure why I haven't found that before.